# how does "decision_function" in scikit-learn calculates the scores?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I want to define how the `decision_function()` works, I mean, if there is something equivalent to be able to report that function in a work. I want to see this information in SVC in scikit-learn, and I am using linear, poly and rbf kernel.

I'm training my models with "ovr" multiclass approach, but I can't find how the scores are calculated to report a function in my article.

Is this even possible in SVM with linear of even with not linear kernels?

Answer (score 2):

Scikit-Learn's SVM classes are based on libsvm. For multiclass classification, libsvm only uses the one-versus-one strategy (`ovo`). Let's say there are 10 classes: it will train a binary classification model for every pair of classes: 1 vs 2, 1 vs 3, 1 vs 4, ..., 1 vs 10, 2 vs 3, 2 vs 4, ..., 2 vs 10, ..., 9 vs 10. That's 45 models in total = 10 * (10 - 1) / 2.

Scikit-Learn's `SVC` class has a `decision_function_shape` hyperparameter which defaults to `ovr` (one-versus-the-rest), but this hyperparameter only affects the output of the `decision_function()` method. The training itself always uses libsvm which is based on the `ovo` strategy.

When you set `decision_function_shape="ovo"`, the `decision_function()` method just returns the confidence score for the positive class for each of the 45 binary classifiers. So the shape of the output will be (num_samples, num_classifiers). If you call it on 3 instances, and there are 10 classes, then the output will have a shape of (3, 45).

However, when you set `decision_function_shape="ovr"` (the default), the `decision_function()` method outputs one score per class. So the output shape is (num_samples, num_classes), for example (3, 10).

How is each score computed in the `ovr` case? Well, first the function computes the sum of confidence scores for each class. Specifically, since each class is involved in 10 classifiers (out of 45), each class gets a score equal to the sum of its 10 confidence scores. This total confidence score (for each class) goes through a special function: f(x) = x / (3 * (|x| + 1)). This function approaches -1/3 when x approaches -∞, and +1/3 when x approaches +∞. So basically the total confidence score gets squashed between -1/3 and +1/3. Lastly, the final score for each class is equal to the number of votes the class got, minus the number of votes against it, plus the squashed confidence score (which acts as a tie-breaker).

The code is [available here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/5f6e17c084c36e9eaee55a7e05f4b2f43be21a25/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py#L444). Here is the relevant part:

```py
    n_samples = predictions.shape[0]
    votes = np.zeros((n_samples, n_classes))
    sum_of_confidences = np.zeros((n_samples, n_classes))

    k = 0
    for i in range(n_classes):
        for j in range(i + 1, n_classes):
            sum_of_confidences[:, i] -= confidences[:, k]
            sum_of_confidences[:, j] += confidences[:, k]
            votes[predictions[:, k] == 0, i] += 1
            votes[predictions[:, k] == 1, j] += 1
            k += 1

    # Monotonically transform the sum_of_confidences to (-1/3, 1/3)
    # and add it with votes. The monotonic transformation  is
    # f: x -> x / (3 * (|x| + 1)), it uses 1/3 instead of 1/2
    # to ensure that we won't reach the limits and change vote order.
    # The motivation is to use confidence levels as a way to break ties in
    # the votes without switching any decision made based on a difference
    # of 1 vote.
    transformed_confidences = sum_of_confidences / (
        3 * (np.abs(sum_of_confidences) + 1)
    )
    return votes + transformed_confidences
```

Answer (score -1):

From the scikit-learn documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.decision_function :

`decision_function()` takes as parameters an array-like of shape (n_samples, n_features)

It returns as output an ndarray of shape (n_samples, n_classes * (n_classes-1) / 2)

Also note that if decision_function_shape=’ovr’, the shape is (n_samples, n_classes).